# setting height of div container disables click inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is weird. I have an input button inside of 3 divs, the outer-most of which is id'ed as "container". When I set "container"'s height, no action is triggered when I click on the inputs id'ed as "switch" and "next". However, when I do not set a height for #container, the click actions do work. What is causing this? Thank you!
My html and css is below.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv:"Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <script text="text/Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery_home.css">


    <title> jquery home </title>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container"> 

    <h1 style="position: relative; top: 10%; width: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"> Learn jQuery </h1>

<div id="q_and_a_container" style="text-align: center">
    <div style="width: 200px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center" id="qa" height="500px"> Nate</div>
    <input type="submit" id="switch" value="See Answer" /> 
    <input type="submit" id="next" value="Next Question" />


</div>

<div id="answer_container">
    <textarea id="answer_here"> </textarea>
</div>

</div>

<div id="another_container" style="width: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center">

    <h2 style="font-family: 'Chalk'">
<a href="add_question.html">Add question </a> </h2>

</div>





</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Chalk";
    src: url("../../font/KGSecondChancesSketch.ttf");
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Chalk";
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

body {
    background-image: url(../../../img/compressedbgs/chalkboard.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


#q_and_a_container {
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 25%;
    left: 2%;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
        color-stop(0% white), color-stop(15%, white), 
            color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3);
    z-index: 45;
}

div#qa {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    height: 75%;
    z-index: 50;
}

#answer_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 2%;
    width: 45%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin: 1%;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

input {
    width: 107px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
    z-index: 1000;
}

textarea {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Droid Sans Mono";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-appearance: none;
    font-size: medium;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

#add_question {
    clear: both;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;

}

a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var question_number = 1;
    var tempText;
    var qno;


    $(document).on("click", "#switch", function(event) {
        if ($("#switch").val() == "See Answer") {
            tempText = $("#qa").text();
            $("#qa").text("");
            qno = "" + question_number;
            qno = "#" + qno;

            $.ajax({
                url: "answers.html",
                datatype: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#qa").html($(data).filter(qno).text());
                },
                error: function(r) {
                    alert("whoops, error in ajax request");
                }
            }); // end AJAX request

            // change value
            $("#switch").val("See Question");
        } else {

            temptText = $("#qa").text();
            $("#qa").text("");
            qno = "" + question_number;
            qno = "#" + qno;

            $("#qa").text(tempText);            
            $("#switch").val("See Answer");
            }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#next", function(event) {
        question_number = question_number + 1;
        qno = "" + question_number;
        qno = "#" + qno;

        $.ajax({
            url: "questions.html",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#qa").text($(data).filter(qno).text());
            },
            error: function(r) {
                alert("whoops, error in ajax request for next question");
            }
        }); // end AJAX request
    });

    $("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
        // get caret position/selection
        var start = this.selectionStart;
        var end = this.selectionEnd;

        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();

        // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
        $this.val(value.substring(0, start)
                    + "\t"
                    + value.substring(end));

        // put caret at right position again (add one for the tab)
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

        // prevent the focus lose
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});


})
```

Comment: I think when you set height for the container, the clicks are being received by "q_and_a_container" div rather than the buttons. Can you confirm this ?

Comment: Can you add the js function. Also a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: How would I do this? Are you sure it's "q_and_a_container", and not "container"? Because the height of "container" is causing the problems. Just clarifying!

Comment: Just added the js function

Comment: give the container a higher z-index value like 999999

Comment: Yep. A higher z-index didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the z-index for the div is positioning it on top of the inputs. You have set z-index on the inputs but because they are static elements it is ignored.

Add `position:relative;` to the inputs and they will be brought to the front.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonathon Milne! I have been trying to figure it out for about 2 hours. I would accept your answer but I'm not able to now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `div#qa` will overlap the button.
`div#qa` has `z-index: 50;`. change it to -1 will make you button clickable.

```
div#qa {
    height: 75%;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Check [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/03bp8v49/)

Answer (score 0):

*It is happening because of the div (id="qa") before your 2 buttons. you have mentioned a width of 200px and height of 500px which is making it cover the buttons too. As well you have z-index of 50 for it, which is making it come on top of your buttons.*

There are 2 things you can do,

**Either make z-index to some value so that the div comes after button layer (In case you want the div to be of same size)**

Ex -

```
z-index : -50;
```

**or you can decrease the size of div and top margin to be something which will make buttons to come after the div.**

Ex -

```
top : 5%;
height : 200px;
```